# How to rename many images after processing with different parameters

Tags: image, matlab, rename, dilation

Hello dear programmers,
I have a sequence of images and I would like to perform dilation on each of them with different dilation parameters. Then, I would like to save the processed images with new name including both the old name and the corresponding dilation parameter. My codes are as follows.

```
Input_folder = 
Output_folder = 
D = dir([Input_folder '*.jpg']);
Inputs = {D.name}';
Outputs = Inputs; % preallocate
%print(length(Inputs));
for k = 1:length(Inputs)
    X = imread([Input_folder Inputs{k}]);
    dotLocations = find(Inputs{k} == '.');
    name_img = Inputs{k}(1:dotLocations(1)-1);
    image1=im2bw(X);
    vec = [3;6;10];
    vec_l = length(vec);
    for i = 1:vec_l
    %se = strel('disk',2);
        fprintf(num2str(vec(i)));
        se = strel('diamond',vec(i)); %imdilate
        im = imdilate(image1,se);
        image2 = im - image1;
   
        Outputs{k} = regexprep(Outputs{k}, name_img, strcat(name_img,'_', num2str(vec(i))));
        imwrite(image2, [Output_folder Outputs{k}])
    end
end
```

As it can be seen, I would like to apply dilation with parameters 3,6 and 10. Let us assume that an image has as name "image1", after processing it, I would like to have "image1_3", "image1_6" and "image1_10". However, I am getting as results "image1_3", "image1_6_3" and "image1_10_6_3". Please, how can I modify my codes to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you rewrite each item of the `Outputs` variable three times, each time using the previous value to create a new value. Instead, you should use the values stored in `Inputs` new names. Another mistake in your code is that the size of `Inputs` and `Outputs` are equal, while for every file in the input folder, three files must be stored in the output folder.
I also suggest using [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) function, instead of string processing, to get different parts of a file path.

```
vec = [3;6;10];
vec_l = length(vec);
Outputs = cell(size(Inputs, 1)*vec_l, 1); % preallocate
for k = 1:length(Inputs)
    [~,name,ext] = fileparts([Input_folder Inputs{k}]);
    % load image
    for i = 1:vec_l
        % modify image
        newName = sprintf('%s_%d%s', name, vec(i), ext);
        Outputs{(k-1)*vec_l+i} = newName;
        imwrite(image2, [Output_folder newName])
    end
end
```